# SparkSession not picking up Runtime Configuration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, configuration-files

In my application I'm creating a `SparkSession` object and then trying to Read my properties file and setting the properties at runtime. But it is not picking up the properties that I am passing at runtime.

I am submitting my App in YARN Cluster Mode

This is my inital Spark session object which I am creating in a Trait

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("MyApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Then in my main function which is inside an object, i am extending this Trait so my spark session is Initialized in Trait and in my Object (containing main) i am setting this :

```
spark.conf.set(spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet, false)
spark.conf.set(mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive,true)
spark.conf.set(spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled, true)
spark.conf.set(spark.shuffle.service.enabled, true)
spark.conf.set(spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors,40)
```

So Ideally my App must start with 40 Executors but it is starting and then running Entirely using the Default 2 executors ..

Comment: Hi Ajm, did you figure it out? I am still having this issue. When I am setting shuffle partitions within the main method, it didn't work. It only worked if I set it outside the main method, say in the object or class. This is the setting -> `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1700")`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing unexpected here. Only certain subset of Spark SQL properties (prefixed with `spark.sql`) can be set on runtime (see [`SparkConf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.SparkConf) documentation):

> Once a SparkConf object is passed to Spark, it is cloned and can no longer be modified by the user. Spark does not support modifying the configuration at runtime.

Remaining options have to be set before `SparkContext` is initalized. It means initalizing `SparkSession` with `SparkContext`:

```
val conf: SparkConf = ...   // Set options here
val sc  = SparkContext(conf)
val spark  = SparkSession(sc)
```

with `config` method of `SparkSession.Builder` and `SparkConf`

```
val conf: SparkConf = ...   // Set options here
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate
```

or key-value pairs:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.some.key", "some_value").getOrCreate
```

This applies in particular to `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled`,
`spark.shuffle.service.enabled` and `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors`.

`mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive` from the other hand, is a property of Hadoop configuration, not Spark, and should be set there:

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("some.hadoop.property", "some_value")
```

Comment: So are you trying to Say that only Certain Properties can be set at Runtime using spark.conf.set options ..???? 
IF YES then what all are those can u provide me with the specific section in Documentation ??

Comment: mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive from the other hand, is a property of Hadoop configuration, not Spark, and should be set there.  ???
Should be Set WHERE ...?? Did not understood this point & place you are asking to SET ..?

Comment: I am setting shuffle partitions and it didn't work when I am setting it within the main method. It only work if I set it outside the main method, say in the object or class. This is the setting -> `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1700")`